# Does a Maven plugin exist for generating java test classes?

Tags: eclipse, testing

In eclipse is it possible to generate test cases, but they are only templates for method names.

Is there a tool or plugin for Eclipse that generates some more code?

Comment: What else do you want? how can an external tool know the logic of your application? The only think that it could know is the name of the methods. Eventually, it lacks an assistant for assertions, but I do not see other things.

Comment: Also return value. Frequently bugs are about null, empty, undefined  etc. values.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, you ask for a Maven plugin in the title and ask about eclipse in the details.  No tag for maven, even though that is your question title.  Have to agree with @AngocA though, not sure what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your testing framework (JUnit or TestNg, or...).
Since Eclipse [comes with JUnit](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JUnit/article.html#juniteclipse_eclipse), the JUnit.org site has a [list of code generators](http://www.junit.org/taxonomy/term/7) you might consider, but none with the exact feature you are looking for (and none directly integrated as a maven task).